# Magento 2 - Exception #0 (Exception): Failed to parse time string (6 ago. 1943) at position 0 (6): Unexpected character

Tags: magento

we are running a magento 2 webshop where we sell music compilations. Each music compilations has album tracks and as we deal with old music the recording date is important and therefore displayed.
We have 5 stores (engl, german, spanish, italian and french).
the first 2 work fine but with the three romance lang. stores we face an issue.
When clicking on an album to show its content we got the following error messages.

Obviously an issue with the date format in these stores.

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Failed to parse time string (6 ago. 1943) at position 0 (6): Unexpected character

Exception #0 (Exception): Failed to parse time string (6 ago. 1943) at position 0 (6): Unexpected character

#1 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->formatDate() called at 
[generated/code/Devm2/AlbumTrackProduct/Block/Product/ProductList/AlbumTrac k/Interceptor.php:590] 
#2 
Devm2\AlbumTrackProduct\Block\Product\ProductList\AlbumTrack\Interceptor>formatDate() called at 
[app/design/frontend/Devm2/oldtunes/Devm2_AlbumTrackProduct/templates/produ ct/list/items.phtml:99] 
and so forth...

any ideas?
Thanks
Tristan